# how long does it take to guess 4 digit pin when you have all 4 numbers

Tags: probability, combinations

If I have a four digit pin, normally that would be $10000$ combinations ($10^4$), which would take a very long time to guess, however what if the person trying to access the pin had all four digits already (just not the sequence), is this not simply $256$ guesses ($4^4$?)?

How long would it take a person to guess that many times? Is there some probability at play here, perhaps like a $50\%$ chance of getting it right?

(By the way, I am not trying to unlock anything illegally. I've made a game with a passcode use to open certain doorways, and want strike a balance between achievable and hard to guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Mathematics

The idea you should have is that there are four boxes to put digits in, and you have a collection of four digits to put into those boxes.  If you assume that all of the digits are unique, (e.g. you know that the four numbers are `1234`, in some order), then you can put any one of those four digits in the first box.  Once you have used up that digit, there are only three options for the next box, then two options for the next, and the final box is completely determined.  Thus there are
$$ 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 4! = 24$$
possible codes which contain four fixed, unique digits.

This is the worst case scenario.  If there is a repeated digit (e.g., the digits are known to be `1123`), then there are fewer possible combinations.  This can be computed precisely, but for such a small case, it probably doesn't matter.

#### Gameplay

Don't do this.  That is, don't create a "puzzle" where the player might have to just try all possible codes containing four fixed digits.  The satisfaction of solving a puzzle is in feeling like you have done something clever.  Cycling through each of $24$ possible codes is tedious, and doesn't make one feel like they have done anything particularly smart.  It's monkey work (in the sense that a trained monkey could probably do it).  It would be far better to design a puzzle which lets players figure out which digits go into which slots without having to (potentially) try them all out.  Make it possible for players to feel smart.

Answer (score 2):

There are $4! = 24$ ways to arrange four different items. So, that's the worst case scenario.

If you had repeated digits, then it could be even fewer. For example, if you knew that the only digit was an $8$, then you'd get the code on your first guess.

Comment: I suppose this isn't too bad then to just leave people 4 numbers to guess with, as it doesn't seem that 24 guesses would take a long time.

Comment: What if I added one more number? Does the amount of guess grow astronomically?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid The number of ways to arrange $n$ objects is $n! = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 2 \cdot 1$. So, if you had $5$ numbers then you'd have $5! = 120$ combos to try; factorial growth is pretty fast!

Answer (score 2):

As there are 4 different numbers, there will be 4! amount of possibilities:

There are...

- 4 possible results in the first number,
- 3 possible numbers remaining in the second, as one has been already used,
- 2 remaining for the 3rd number in the PIN, as 2 have been taken,
- 1 final item that can be used for the last (all other 3 have been used).
  That will result in

#### $$ 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 4! = 24 $$

There are 24 possible results.

To think of it visually,

You can start with swapping the last 2, which is 2! = 2 scenarios:

```
ABCD, ABDC.
```

However, if you swap the last *3*:

```
ABCD,
ABDC,
ACDB,
ACBD,
ADCB,
ADBC,
BACD,
BADC,
```

There are 6 values, because 3! = 6, and we are swapping the last 3.

Same applies for 4 values. 4! = **24**.

The probability for getting it correct at random would then be `1/24`, because there are 24 possible values, and the user would choose a random one. It would be ≈ 4.1%